# emit (action) signal from gst-launch-1.0 pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I've got a rtsp cam with backchannel support and I'm trying to get it to work with the command line tool gst-launch-1.0. The incoming streams are not an issue, but the backchannel when enabled doesn't produce a sink. however I've digged through the sources and got this little hint from the developer from the element rtspsrc:

> Set backchannel=onvif to enable, and use the 'push-backchannel-sample'
>   action signal with the correct stream id.

I can't seem to find any info about (action) signals on the command line for gst-launch-1.0

Does anyone know if it is even possible to send signals from gst-launch-1.0?

Thanks,

Bram

Answer (score 0):

I think this is meant to be called from code and not usable from [gst-launch-1.0](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html).

Just for reference, the [signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/signal.html) is called [`push-backchannel-buffer`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtspsrc.html#GstRTSPSrc-push-backchannel-buffer) (not `-sample`).

Also, the above linked manual page for gst-launch-1.0 says:

> Please note that gst-launch-1.0 is primarily a debugging tool. You
>   should not build applications on top of it. For applications, use the
>   gst_parse_launch() function of the GStreamer API as an easy way to
>   construct pipelines from pipeline descriptions.